# Add values using ContentValues giving Null pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

`public class addbudget extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
DBhelper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
EditText txtBudget;
TextView txr;
ListView rldlist;
Button btn66;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addbudget);

    btn66=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addBudget);
    btn66.setOnClickListener(this);

    txr=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.addbud);

    txtBudget=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBudget);

    rldlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rldlist);

    Bundle data_from_list= getIntent().getExtras();
    String value_in_tv= data_from_list.getString("passed data key");
    txr.setText(value_in_tv);

}

 private void clearfield(){
    txtBudget.setText("");

}


public void onClick(View v) {
    if (btn66 == v) {
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.put(DBhelper.Amount, txtBudget.getText().toString());
        value.put(DBhelper.Description,txr.getText().toString());

        if (txtBudget.length() == 0) {
            txtBudget.requestFocus();
            txtBudget.setError("Field Cannot Be Empty");
        } else {
            db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(DBhelper.TABLE2, null, value);
            db.close();
            clearfield();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Budget add Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
}
}
```

`

This is my Activity,where I want to insert values to the database,Inside Onclicklistener,I have my code to add data to database,

I need to add "Textview txr" value and "EditText txtBudget" value to database,I'm retrieving value for "Textview txr" from another activity using Bundle.

Now the problem is,I'm getting Null pointer exception,When I click the Add Button.Help me to solve this out.

`10-12 22:23:17.142  11785-11785/com.example.username.god E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.username.god.addbudget.onClick(addbudget.java:92)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18398)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

line causing issue because `helper` object is `null`.

Need to initilize helper object before using it to call methods :

```
 helper=new DBhelper(addbudget.this);
 db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: @xyz: see my updated answer.if still facing same issue then plz share `DBhelper` class code with question also